# Convert Varchar into Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

How do i convert the Time format  ***" 10:02:22 PM "*** into an SQL Server DateTime Format.

I have a column of such data. I imported this column from a CSV File and now want to convert it into a DateTime Format so that i can be able to use Date Time Functions.

I want to be able to insert this column into another table with correct DateTime format.

Comment: Is the space in that time data really present?

Comment: Date and time values are stored in DB without any format. It is client application format date and time values.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Yes the space is present before AM/PM.

Comment: @Igor: There is no client side application here. Just a huge dump of CSV Files that i have to load into SQL Server. All the required operations are to be done using SQL.

Comment: @SarangArd It was comment on this `I want to be able to insert this column into another table with correct DateTime format.`

Comment: @Igor: Got it bud. But i still haven't managed to solve the problem.
Its kinda my bottle-neck now as i can't proceed further. :(

Answer (score 6):

Use this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

For only time conversion...

```
SELECT CONVERT( TIME, '10:00:22 PM' );
```

Gives the following output...

```
22:00:22.000000
```

Time conversion with date and time...

```
SELECT CONVERT( DATETIME, '10:00:22 PM' );
```

Gives the following output...

```
1900-01-01 22:00:22.0000
```

Note : For `datetime` you need to have specific date as input otherwise it consider default century date.

Comment: For some reason the Convert Fails when i try to convert the column. But it succeeds when I do it individually.

May i know why?

Comment: It is able to convert AM Values but not PM Values.

It isn't able to convert "00:00:01 PM" to "00:59:59 PM"
But it can convert "01:00:00 PM"

Can you help me on that??

Comment: In 12 hours system there is not 00 hours that is the reason you conversation is failing.

Comment: while you are converting column value how are you using it?

Comment: In 12 hours system we have  00:00:01 AM, but in case of PM we do not have  00:00:01 PM it must be 12:00:01 PM, likewise we do have 12:59:59 PM, 01:00:00 PM is valid in case of 12 hours system.

Comment: Well explained time confusion to the people. [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it. An implicit cast occurs when you use

```
INSERT otherTable
SELECT ....., timeAsVarchar, ...
  FROM csvTable
```

If all the time data (leading space or not) is parseable from the string, the query will work beautifully.  If however, there is the possibility of bad or blank data that cannot be converted to a time, test it first

```
INSERT otherTable
SELECT ....., CASE WHEN ISDATE(timeAsVarchar)=1 THEN timeAsVarchar END, ...
  FROM csvTable
```

`ELSE NULL` is implied so I left it out.

Comment: The Implicit Cast Conversion fails and i get the error, "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

So what do I do. How do i define the Time column in the "otherTable"??