# converting a hour:min:ss value from varchar to time format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns 'START','END'. In these columns my data like this:

```
START   END
161925  161926
155225  155226
000000  100000
170000  170001
170109  170110
184254  184255
171543  171544
000000  100000
```

These columns are in varchar datatype and i want to convert them in Time datatype(hour:min:sec)
I used substring function to first get this value in hour:min:sec by using:

```
select substring(START,0,3)+':'+ substring(START,3,2)+':'+ substring(START,5,2)
from Table_Name
```

Now I am facing problem to converting this into time format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Varchar into Time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075331/convert-varchar-into-time-in-sql-server)

Comment: Nothing has changed since your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803502/cast-nvarchar-to-time-getting-error-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and); there are *still* only 60 seconds in a minute and there are only 60 minutes in an hour. `157890` makes no sense when converted to `15:78:90`. What "time" is `15:78:90`.? Are you working in some odd environment where there are 100 seconds in a minute and 100 minutes to an hour?

Comment: Please, explain what time `'157890'`  is supposed to represent. `'15:78:90'` is not a valid time. Is it `15.7890` hours in decimal format maybe?

Comment: Unless you show us what the expected results are for the above *and* the logic to get those results, we can't help you.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have just converted '157890' in hour:min:sec format, now i have to convert this in time format, which i am not able to understand. I have to first convert this in valid format as you said so please help me with this

Comment: ... @user123 *again*, `157890` is the format `hh:mm:ss` makes no sense... `15:78:90` Is **not** a valid time. There are only 60 seconds in a minute, and only 60 minutes in an hour. What "time" is "78 minutes past 15 o'clock"? 16:18? Does that mean that `15:78:90` is *actually* `16:19:30` when using a normal clock?

Comment: @Larnu Please see my reply to Olivier

Comment: You don't tell us what "time" `157890` is in that [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807019/converting-a-hourminss-value-from-varchar-to-time-format#comment119852125_67807019), @user123 ...

Comment: @Larnu I am sorry, I corrected the value please check

Comment: The first `substring` should be `substring(START,1,2)`. That would be more consistent, as the positions are 1-based.

Answer (score 3):

I've repeated myself so many times here (and in your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803502/cast-nvarchar-to-time-getting-error-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and)) in the comments that I'm just going to post an answer explaining the problem here:

There are **only** 60 minutes in an hour, and there are **only** 60 seconds in a minute. According to a [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+long+has+there+been+60+seconds+in+a+minute%3F) this has been the case since around 3500BC<sup>1</sup>; so for roughly 5,500 years at the time of writing. You have "times" like `187654` and `157890` so I can only assume that you are working with times from pre 3,500BC.

SQL Server doesn't work with BC dates, even in the newest date and time data types, such as `datetime2`; which has an upper limit of `9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999` and a lower limit of `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000`. As such the times you have *cannot* be stored in a `time` data type, as that expects a value between `00:00:00.0000000` and `23:59:59.9999999`.

As such, if you want to store your values in "time like" format, you will have to use a `varchar` and add the `:` characters. I prefer to use `STUFF` to do this:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(START,5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS StartTime,
       STUFF(STUFF([END],5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS EndTime
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Trying to `CONVERT` some of these values to `time`, however, will yield an error. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(STUFF(157890,5,0,':'),3,0,':')) AS StartTime;
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If you just want the valid times by "modern" standards, then you could use `TRY_CONVERT`, which will return `NULL` for pre circa 3500BC times:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(STUFF(START,5,0,':'),3,0,':')) AS StartTime,
       TRY_CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(STUFF([END],5,0,':'),3,0,':')) AS EndTime
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=586fa6a73fd3cb5084fa21ef489f571a)

<sup>1.
[Why are there 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour and 24 hours in a day? Who decided on these time divisions?](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-1487,00.html)</sup>

*This answer is based on [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67807019/2) of the question*

Comment: As amusing as I found this answer, I think OP has edited the question to clarify that the input data should, in fact, be valid times in the modern (i.e. POST-3500BC) sense

Comment: Yeah, they have, @Martin . Unfortunately(?) I had written almost all of this time by time they did and I was (as I mention in the answer) "tired" of asking "What 'time' is `157890`?".

Comment: Having followed the conversation across both questions, I entirely sympathise with your frustrations!

Comment: @Larnu this is working. now I want to subtract START from END ,BUT IT IS SHOWING ERROR

Comment: *"now I want to subtract START from END ,BUT IT IS SHOWING ERROR"* That is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), @user123 . But Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo/{Insert Other Search Engine here} it; you'll find the answer with minimal effort.

Comment: Just search for `DATE_DIFF`... e.g. `DATE_DIFF(SECOND, StartDate, EndDate)`...

Comment: That looks nothing like the SQL I have given you, @user123 ...

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the answer demonstrating it works for you, @user123.

Comment: @Larnu I guess it does - just extended by his own column names and my date_diff. It's basically the extended version of your last SQL statement. Anyways user123: WHICH error does it show? I just executed the statement on a sample table and it worked as expected.

Comment: This should *really* be a new question, as I mentioned though, @Tyron78 . The comments aren't for answering a new question as the OP has added new requirements to the question. A new question needs to be posted (which'll likely quickly be closed as a duplicate unless the OP shows their attempt in the question).

Comment: ... @user123 with the greatest of respect, I am growing tired of repeating myself. Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your *new* problem...

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have corrected the example to represent valid times, here is a possible solution:

You can use the `TIMEFROMPARTS` function and some math to extract the parts

```sql
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(
    CONVERT(int, START) / 10000,
    CONVERT(int, START) % 10000 / 100,
    CONVERT(int, START) % 100, 0, 0) AS start_time
FROM dbo.StartEnd
```

or with SUBSTRING:

```sql
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(START,1,2)),
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(START,3,2)),
    CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(START,5,2)), 0, 0) AS start_time
FROM dbo.StartEnd
```